# is it possible to make background:cover; effect for <video></video> tag and center it?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make `background:cover;` effect for `<video></video>` tag and center it?

I tried just like for image but it does not work. I think it's because video tag is not the background of the `<div>`, but then how to make it work? Or how to do that it would be background video?

```html
<div class="" style="width:90%; 
height:300px; border:1px solid red;
background-color:blue; background-size:cover;
 margin:0 auto; ">
<video width="100%" style="margin-top:-100px;" controls autoplay loop muted>
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent property to `background-image` for video tags is `object-fit`.

```
video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Note, however, that the property is currently [incompatible with IE/Edge](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit).

Comment: Thank you very much I really appreciate it . it centered my video and placed controls in divs bottom but video outpouring . and in css style sheet it looks like css does not recognizing. cos color is black in stylesheet .

Comment: That sounds like a new issue. Can you reproduce it in a JSFiddle and link it here? Also, if this answered your original question, feel free to click the checkmark to mark it solved.

Comment: sorry am very new here could u tell me what is JSFiddle? its like post code section ?

Comment: Yes, it's a website where you can post HTML/CSS code. If you can show the problem on there, we could help more.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41293452/how-to-make-video-video-tag-in-div-center-without-video-outpouring