# how to make <video></video> tag in div center without video outpouring?

Tags: html, css

it centered my video and placed controls in divs bottom but video outpouring . and in css style sheet it looks like css does not recognizing. cos color is black in stylesheet. i use chrome .

```css
div.video_div{
 width:800px;
 height:300px;
 border:1px solid red;
 background-color:blue;
 margin:0 auto;
}
video{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 object-fit:cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>video</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="video_div">
<video controls autoplay loop muted>
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By "video outpouring", do you mean you want the video centered and contained instead of covering/cropping? You'd use `object-fit: contain` for that instead of `object-fit: cover`. See the difference here in the Demo (scroll down): https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/

Comment: yes instead croping. object-fit:contain; does not stretch 100% in div it shows in the middle whit full height .   but thnx its beter than before .

Comment: object-fit:fill; looks something i need just video gets compressed height .i need it in original pixels with full width .and height like it would be in background cover effect css .and center it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the rule overflow: hidden; to your div.video_div rule:

```
div.video_div{
    width:800px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid red;
    background-color:blue;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow: hidden; /* Add this */
}
video{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    /* Use contain instead if you want the object to fit without cropping */
    object-fit: cover; 
}
```

The object-fit: cover attribute will scale the video, preserving aspect. This can leave part of it overflowing over the boundaries. The overflow: hidden CSS on the surrounding div hides this overflow. You might also want to use object-fit: contain instead, which will preserve aspect ratio, but make the video completely fit inside the box. (You can check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit to see the various values.)

Example jsfiddle with a working video source:
https://jsfiddle.net/gmg43wb2/

Comment: thnx it works u are amazing ! i used  object-fit: cover; and it centered the video ...u are good :)